# Regions /patterns in images that creates classification

Tags: predictive-modeling, deep-learning, image-classification, image-recognition

I am  having  some images on which  I   trained some neural   network  models in order to  do classification( binary  task).
I am interested  of a  method    to identify  some patterns  or regions  in those images  that are  influencial  the classification   part in  other words  what  regions or  what patterns are formed  for a particular  class.

Comment: Like that? http://heatmapping.org/caffe.html They link some interesting papers that should get you further.

Answer (score 1):

I think visualizing convolutional neural networks is what you want.

[CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io) is a good place to start, here is a step-by-step [guide](http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/) about how to visualize the activations, first-layer weights, and shows how to retrieve images which maximally activate a neuron.

Also there's a [demo](https://transcranial.github.io/keras-js/) which visualized multiple convnets (including ResNet50, Inception v3, etc). You may learn a lot from this demo (at least I do).

If you're interesting in details, this well-known [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901) may help you.